# Change font by button onclick or script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a button that changes an element's font-family by clicking a button.

Here's what I have done;

```html
<h2 id="idname">My title</h2>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('idname').style.font-family = 'Georgia'">
Click Me!</button>
```

What should I do to complete this script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change font inside a javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749769/how-to-change-font-inside-a-javascript-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `.style.fontFamily` instead of `.style.font-family`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change an element's CSS style by using javascript, you must use the camelCase syntax for the rules. change `"font-family"` with `"fontFamily"`

```html
<h2 id="idname">My title</h2>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('idname').style.fontFamily = 'Georgia'">
Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a logical error in your javascript. CSS properties that includes a `-` in their property name are always targetted as camel case in javascript.

**For reference:**

**CSS notation**  ------  **JavaScript notation**

`font-family` -> `fontFamily`

`font-size` -> `fontSize`

`background-color` -> `backgroundColor`

Hence your code will be:

```html
<h2 id="idname">My title</h2>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('idname').style.fontFamily = 'Georgia'">
Click Me!</button>
```